# You have been disconnected, please check your internet connection Jitsi Meet

Tags: flutter, jitsi-meet, video-conferencing

I am working on Zoom clone(video conferencing app) in Flutter and for that, I'm using **jitsi_meet: ^4.0.0**, and when I tried to create a new meeting it shows me this screen for milliseconds and then return me to the home screen. My internet connection is Ok, What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: have you found the solution ?

Comment: @MDZDN if you're stuck on this problem, might I suggest using an alternative to Jitsi? I am Developer Advocate at 100ms and we have a complete piece on building a Zoom clone in Flutter with the 100ms SDK. Find it here: https://www.100ms.live/blog/zoom-clone-in-flutter